# What is difference between Misuse intrusion and Signature Based IDS?

Tags: intrusion-prevention

Can someone explain me this ? I have been searching the difference between misuse intrusion and signature based over the internet and I have come to a certain point where after reading so many articles the difference between the two seems blurry.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Misuse detection is a broader form of detection based on network behavior, rather than a specific kind of traffic or content.(signature)

In Misuse detection:
If an endpoint is sending out a larger then usual amount of ARP traffic, then it may be detected as misuse. The actual fact that ARP traffic is being sent is not the misuse, but the amount or pattern of the traffic may be detected as misuse.

In a signature based scenario, if the contents or kinds of traffic sent out by an endpoint are prohibited (example: workstation acting as a rogue dhcp server), then it will be flagged as intrusion or a risk. The signature is the fact that the endpoint is running a service that it is not supposed to run under any situation. The IDS sees a protocol related signature and determines that traffic should never occur from the source IP.(or to a destination IP, it is situation dependent)

Yes, this is a bit of a blurry distinction, but think of misuse detection as more "sensitive" (prone to false alarm), and signature based as more "accurate".(prone to missing some threats, abnormality)

Comment: Pretty good summary - however, the distinction becomes much more blurry across vendors (where they could call misuse patterns signatures and vice versa)...